# fprintf in do while loop wrote only one line in file C

Tags: c, printf, do-while

I don't know why it is writing only one line in my file

```
void foo()
{
int ID;
char answer;
FILE *input = fopen("Dane.txt", "w");

do
{
    printf("Give ID: ");
    scanf("%d",&ID);
    fprintf(input, "%d\n", ID);
    printf("Exit? y/n ");
    scanf("%s", &answer);
    fflush(NULL);

}
while (answer != 'n');

fclose(input);
}
```

Output (in file) is only first ID number which I write on console. But where are others?

EDIT: ok I got it. The error was in `char answer`and it should be `char answer[2]` and ending while should be `while(answer[0] != ...)`. Before it the program read only one character - the line end. When i hit e.g. "n ENTER" it take only ENTER. Now it take the first char from tab i.e. "n". Thank everybody for help

Comment: Does your program repeat the first question after you answer 'n' to the "Exit? y/n " question?

Comment: This code is incorrect: scanf is being asked to read a string, which could be of any length, and will have a NUL character appended. So it the user answers y or n, at least two bytes will be written - the NULL might overwrite other data in the stack and crash the program.

Comment: Ok, sorry for this backward question, i translated it from my language and I did mistake. However this isn't important. The point is, why program print only one line in file?

Comment: @Andrew because, just after taking one input, the condition in while loop fails and the program terminates. Basic difference between do-while and while is: do-while works for at least once, but while may works for zero times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing some logical mistake. You are asking whether exit or not. If user does not want to exit, then he would press `n`. So, to continue the loop, the answer should be equal to `n`, right?

#### Modified version of your program:

```
void foo()
{
    int ID;
    char answer;
    FILE *input = fopen("Dane.txt", "w");

    do
    {
        printf("Give ID: ");
        scanf("%d",&ID);
        fprintf(input, "%d\n", ID);
        printf("Exit? y/n ");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);
        fflush(NULL);

    }
    while (answer == 'n');

    fclose(input);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I ran your function, I got all three numbers I entered in the file:

```
$ ./a.out
Give ID: 25
Exit? y/n y
Give ID: 33
Exit? y/n y
Give ID: 10
Exit? y/n n
$ cat Dane.txt
25
33
10
```

However, your question is backwards.  You ask, "Exit? y/n" and then exit if the answer is "n" ("no").  The question should be "Continue? y/n", so that when the user answers in the affirmative, it continues.

Also, naming your output filehandle "input" is backwards, and as others have mentioned, your `answer` variable should be a character array of at least 2 characters, as `char answer[2];`.

Comment: Sorry for this backward question, i translated it from my language and I did logical mistake. It works good. However this isn't important. The point is, why program print only one line in file?

Comment: As I said, it worked properly for me.  I gave it three numbers, and it wrote all three into the file.  Perhaps you need to give more detail on how you're using the program.  One thing to note is it's going to replace the file each time you run it, so you'll only get the IDs you gave in the last run.

Comment: `char answer; ... scanf("%s", &answer);` is undefined behavior as there is not enough room in `answer` to store a string from `scanf()`.  If anything "works", it is just luck.

Comment: Alright, so program is asking for ID. You write your ID and hit ENTER. Then program asking for ID again (and again and again). So I want to write every new ID under the last one; in new line. I thought loop do while will be printing every ID in new line.
something like:
203492
129456
124566
etc.

Comment: If you copy-and-paste a transcript of you running the program in a terminal, it might shed some light on why it isn't working for you.

Comment: @Chad ok. So it's look that: Give ID: 123456 ENTER Give ID: 76543 ENTER Give ID: 000934 ENTER etc. Every ID should be saved in file in new line

Answer (score 1):

- `answer` has only one space to read and it isn't capable to store string whose length is 1 character or longer.
- This won't affect the result, but using `input` for output file pointer is confusing.
- The conditio in `while` is unnatural.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo();
int main() {foo(); return 0;}

void foo()
{
    int ID;
    char answer[4];
    FILE *output = fopen("Dane.txt", "w");
    if (output == NULL) return;

    do
    {
        printf("Give ID: ");
        if (scanf("%d",&ID) != 1) break;
        fprintf(output, "%d\n", ID);
        printf("Exit? y/n ");
        if (scanf("%3s", answer) != 1) break;
        fflush(NULL);

    }
    while (answer[0] != 'y');

    fclose(output);
}
```